# Setting up a graph with 3 variables

Tags: r

```
w         = -1.25
pqxf      <- function(y){(1)*(y)} # replace 1 with py and assign a value to py
pqyf      <- function(x){(w * 16)-(w * x)} # 
utilityf  <- function(x, y, w) { pqyf(x) * pqxf(y)* w} # the utility       function C,l
hours     <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20)

#functions are turned into data frames`

pqy     <- data.frame("consumption" = 
                    pqyf(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20)))`
pqx     <- data.frame("leisure"= 
                           pqxf(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20)))
utility <- data.frame("utility"     = 
                    utilityf(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20)))
```

When I try to run this I get an error:

```
Error in pqxf(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default`
```

How do define `y` ?

Comment: in the last line you use your function `utilityf`. This function aks for three arguments (`x,y,w`), but you only pass one argument (a single list) to the function. Try calling `utilityf(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20), c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20), w)`

Comment: is the function passed w? which is a constant.

Comment: you defined your function to take three arguments (without specific default values). So you need to submit `w` explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about defining and calling functions in R.

You define the function `utilityf` to take three arguments `x,y,w`.
These variables are then used inside the function to invoke other functions.
Since you don't define default values in the declaration of `utilityf` you **need** to pass values to the function. How would `pqxf` you call in `utilityf` know what `y` is?

You declare `w` in your script. However, `utilityf` *does not know* that you want it to use `w=-1.25`.

Try the following:

```
w = -1.25
x = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20)
y = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20)

pqxf      <- function(y){(1)*(y)}
pqyf      <- function(x){(w * 16)-(w * x)}
utilityf  <- function(x, y, w) { pqyf(x) * pqxf(y)* w}

utility <- data.frame("utility" = utilityf(x,y,w)
```

or alternatively:

```
w = -1.25
x = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20)
y = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20)

pqxf      <- function(y){(1)*(y)}
pqyf      <- function(x){(w * 16)-(w * x)}
utilityf  <- function(x, y) { pqyf(x) * pqxf(y)* w}

utility <- data.frame("utility" = utilityf(x,y)
```

In the last case, the function `utilityf` takes the 'global' value of `w`.
In both cases `w` stays constant since you don't change the value anywhere.

**Just a small addition:**

You can set default values for your function like

```
my_f <- function(w=-1.25) {w*10}
```

Calling the function with and without passing a value for `w`:

```
> my_f()
  [1] -12.5
```

And with a value for `w` (pi in this case):

```
> my_f(pi)
  [1] 31.41593
```

Comment: @user801855 this is certainly a different question you should ask elsewhere.